# A react library to show 360 videos and images?

Tags: reactjs, 360-degrees, 360-video

I want to show local 360 videos and images in reactjs. It does not need to actually support VR, just panning around the 360 videos and images with a mouse/touch.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Did you try this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-360-view

Comment: I'm afraid that's not what I'm looking for. That library just uses a bunch of images and swaps between them and I need something to view a 3d image like a single VR frame would be and VR video.